# Distribution items into buckets based on multiple variables

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science

So I have N items, each with two parameters, i.e `Item1{x: 10, y: 20}`, and M buckets, where M < N. Buckets have these `x` and `y` too, meaning that a bucket with `{x: 100, y: 100}` can only hold a number of items whose cumulative Xs and Ys don't exceed these of given bucket. So, for example, a `Bucket{x: 100, y: 100}` could hold no more than 5 instances of Item1 mentioned before.

The goal is to distribute items between buckets more or less evenly while fitting the maximum number of items possible into each bucket.

I'm pretty sure that this is a well-known problem but I don't know its name. And is there any common algorithms for solving this kind of problems?

Comment: sounds like bin packing

Comment: Yeah, this sounds quite a lot like [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) which is NP-hard so you'll probably need to go with some approximate solution.

Comment: You could model it as an integer program and use e.g. GLPK, NumPy/SciPy, Gurobi, CPLEX to solve. But this would take exponential time in the input size. For larger instances it'd be better to come up with a dynamic programming approach.